# Storing an image BLOB after migrating from JPA 1.0 to JPA 2.0

Tags: java, jpa, websphere, jpa-2.0, openjpa

We are in migration process to migrate some application to WAS liberty profile, the application was using open jpa version 1 and java 6 and the code was working just fine , we decided to migrate to JPA 2.0 , and java version 8 because it is implemented in apache open jpa in order to avoid migration issues, now the application is not able to persist a picture in oracle DB , it is stored as a blob datatype filed in a table, we are able to retrieve the image from database correctly but not able to store any in the database due to the below error while commit the storing image query.  I have noticed that it failed to get a place holder for the blob data type field.

Field declaration :

```
@Lob
@Column(name="FORM" ,columnDefinition="BLOB" ,  nullable=true )
private byte[] form;
```

storing Transaction

```
  @Action(Action.ACTION_TYPE.CREATE)
public void createTransaction(final Transaction transaction) throws Exception {
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    try {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(transaction);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        try {
            if (em.getTransaction().isActive()) {
                em.getTransaction().rollback();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        em.close();
        this.emf.close();
        this.emf = null;
    }
}
```

JPA project setting:
Platform : Generic 2.0   ,  JPA Implementation : Library provided by target Runtime.

Exception Stack trace :

```
       [err] <openjpa-2.2.3-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1802153 fatal store error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.RollbackException: The transaction has been rolled back.  See the nested exceptions for details on the errors that occurred.
[err]   at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.commit(EntityManagerImpl.java:594)
[err]   at com.test.hace.sfp.dao.entities.controller.TransactionManager.createTransaction(TransactionManager.java:92)
[err]   at com.test.hace.sfp.services.process.impl.TransactionServiceImpl.submitNewTransactionToApproval(TransactionServiceImpl.java:115)
[err]   at pagecode.pages.branch.initiator.NewTransactionStep2.doSubmitAction(NewTransactionStep2.java:229)
[err]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[err]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[err]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[err]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
[err]   at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:245)
[err]   at [internal classes]
[err]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
[err]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
[err]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[err] Caused by: <openjpa-2.2.3-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1802153 fatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: The transaction has been rolled back.  See the nested exceptions for details on the errors that occurred.
[err]   at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.newFlushException(BrokerImpl.java:2352)
[err]   at [internal classes]
[err]   ... 45 more
[err] Caused by: <openjpa-2.2.3-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1802153 fatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: oracle.sql.BLOB
[err]   at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.narrow(DBDictionary.java:4998)
[err]   at [internal classes]
[err]   ... 52 more
[err] Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: oracle.sql.BLOB
[err]   at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.OracleDictionary.getEmptyBlob(OracleDictionary.java:1249)
[err]   at [internal classes]
[err]   ... 59 more
```

Comment: is this the whole exception stacktrace? if there is more, can you please post it all

Comment: Thanks for your comment I have updated the Full stack trace,

Comment: one small thing that I doubt ... why are you using a snapshot of openjpa ? using a release is always better because it's stable ... also is there anything more available in the stacktrace ?

Comment: The implementation library is provided by target runtime (IBM WAS liberty) ,  i didn't copy any jars to my project, there is nothing in stack trace more than console other than this.

Comment: Also Osama, I noticed interesting thing when i googled OracleDictionary Class and mothed  getEmptyBlob ,  it used to declare a empty object from blob failed as a place holder, and in this method there is a find method for class called oracle.sql.BLOB, which should be exist in the JDBC implementation library for Oracle ojdbc7.jar , this library is defined in the Datasource configured in the application

Comment: I was looking at the class now .... can you please try the same with a very small image ... let's see the cases that generate the problem

Comment: @osamayaccoub The branch of OpenJPA that we ship (2.2.x) with WebSphere V8.5.5/V9/Liberty is an IBM controlled branch -- nothing goes into it without WebSphere release management's blessing.  While SNAPSHOT looks awful, it's harmless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some operations (particularly involving LOBs), JPA Providers (OpenJPA, Eclipselink) will require the JDBC classes to be resolvable by the application's classloader (more specifically, the thread context classloader, which is the app classloader).

The problem is that the javax.sql.DataSource resolved by the JNDI lookup doesn't automatically add those JDBC classes to the application classloader (you really don't want to pollute an applications' ClassLoader with unnecessary libraries, after all.)

However, if you add to your application's definition the JDBC libraries as a shared library as a  definition with your app's entry in server.xml, then it will work.

For example:

```
    <jdbcDriver id="Derby" libraryRef="JDBCLib"/>
    <library filesetRef="DerbyFileset" id="JDBCLib"/>
    <fileset dir="/derby/lib" id="DerbyFileset"/>

    <dataSource id="jdbc/JPA_DS"
                    jndiName="jdbc/JPA_DS"
                    jdbcDriverRef="Derby"
                    isolationLevel="TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED">
                    <properties.derby.client 
                        databaseName="TestDB"
                        serverName="localhost" 
                        portNumber="1527"/>
    </dataSource>

    <application type="ear" id="entity10"         name="Entity10"
       location="${fvt.home}/testbuckets/jpaspec-1.0/Entity/Entity10.ear">
       <classloader commonLibraryRef="JDBCLib" />
    </application>
```

Comment: thanks this is really helpful it works now, i spend almost 5 days trying to make it work I really appreciate.

Comment: guys from inside the kitchen know the recipe well :) ;)